# Couldn't map index in elastic 5.6

Tags: elasticsearch, mapping

Hi I have used elastic version 1.6 previously and did mapping for index as below,

//jarSetup.json

```
mappings": {
 "jardata": {
   "properties": {
     "groupID": {
      "index": "not_analyzed",
      "type": "string"
      },
     "artifactID": {
     "index": "not_analyzed",
     "type": "string"
      },
      "directory": {
      "type": "string"
      },
      "jarFileName": {
      "index": "not_analyzed",
      "type": "string"
      },
      "version": {
      "index": "not_analyzed",
      "type": "string"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

And I run the command `curl -XPOST http://localhost:9200/testjar -d @jarSetup.json` to do the mapping. It worked fine in elastic version 1.6. But when I tried the exact same thing in version 5.6 it gives me an error

```
No handler found for uri [/testjardata] and method [POST]
```

I couldn't figure out what the problem is. If some one know anything about this please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the PUT method when creating an index

```
curl -XPUT http://localhost:9200/testjar -d @jarSetup.json
```

Moreover, analyzed string fields are now called `text` and not analyzed string fields are called `keyword`, so your `jarSetup.json` file should look like this instead:

```
mappings": {
 "jardata": {
   "properties": {
     "groupID": {
      "type": "keyword"
      },
     "artifactID": {
     "type": "keyword"
      },
      "directory": {
      "type": "text"
      },
      "jarFileName": {
      "type": "keyword"
      },
      "version": {
      "type": "keyword"
      }
    }
  }
}
```